# template inheritance C++ iterator

Tags: c++

```
    template<class T, template<typename> class Seq>
    class SequenceWithApply : public Seq<T*>
    {
    public:
      // 0 arguments, any type of return value:
      template<class R>
      void apply(R (T::*f)()) {
        iterator it = begin();
        while(it != end()) {
          ((*it)->*f)();
          it++; }
      }

      // 1 argument, any type of return value:
      template<class R, class A>
      void apply(R(T::*f)(A), A a) {
        iterator it = begin();
        while(it != end()) {
          ((*it)->*f)(a);
          it++; }
      }

      // 2 arguments, any type of return value:
      template<class R, class A1, class A2>
      void apply(R(T::*f)(A1, A2),
                 A1 a1, A2 a2) {
        iterator it = begin();
        while(it != end()) {
          ((*it)->*f)(a1, a2);
          it++;
        }
      }
    }; ///:~

//: C03:applyGromit2.cpp
// Test applyMember.h
#include "Gromit.h"
#include "applyMember.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  SequenceWithApply<Gromit, vector> dogs;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    dogs.push_back(new Gromit(i));
  dogs.apply(&Gromit::speak, 1);
  dogs.apply(&Gromit::eat, 2.0f);
  dogs.apply(&Gromit::sleep, 'z', 3.0);
  dogs.apply(&Gromit::sit);
} ///:~
```

I did not quite understand why compiler complain about `iterator` here. Since this snippet code implemente a class `SequenceWithApply` based on the template. In this case, 
`SequenceWithApply` is actually a based class of `vector`. iterator should be visible in this base class. I really appreciate that someone can help me figure this out.

Comment: I know there's a dupe somewhere out there, but `typename Seq<T*>::iterator`.

Comment: It is not just `iterator`, but also `begin()` and `end()`. I have no clue why this does not work. :(

Comment: If I could find a dupe, it would explain that these names are looked up before the template is instantiated, which means that it can't know which concrete base type to look in.

Comment: @chris you should create a canonical duplicate :)

Comment: @chris So This post is a duplicated question? If it is, I will delete this post. :)

Comment: No, we don't delete duplicate questions, we just redirect them to the duplicate. But it's hard to find a good one in this case

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply write the apply function as a free template function? the standard already has `std::for_each(iter, iter, func)`.

Comment: @RichardHodges I am learning template programming right now. This is a snippet I copied from books.

Comment: @zhexuany ok, in that case I'll post an alternate way of handling this, just for the sake of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler looks for `iterator` on first-phase lookup, which is before the template is ever instantiated. In order to know from which type the class derives, the template must be instantiated (so that `Seq<T*>` is an actual type). Thus, the compiler never finds `iterator` in the base class yet.

You can get around this in two easy ways:

A one-off:

```
typename Seq<T*>::iterator
```

A type alias in your derived class:

```
using iterator = typename Seq<T*>::iterator;
```

All of these unambiguously specify to which type `iterator` belongs, looked up in the second phase of lookup when `Seq` and `T` are known. [More on `typename`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

You can do the same for your functions:

A one-off:

```
Seq<T*>::begin()
this->begin() // if inside a member function
```

A using declaration:

```
using Seq<T*>::begin;
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. We also need add `Seq<T*>::` to `begin()` and `end()`. In addition, there is another question about the code. On the first line of this snippet, we need add variadic templates. ie. `template<class T, template<typename...> class Seq>`

Comment: @zhexuany, `std::vector` has more than one type parameter. Other standard containers have differing numbers. To support their usage more uniformly, you can accept any number of type parameters.

Comment: Yeah. Your answer is great. Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: `decltype(*this)` is going to be a reference type that you can't use `::` on.

Comment: @T.C., That's what I get for not instantiating the template when testing. I removed them. While `std::decay_t<decltype(*this)>::iterator` should work to not repeat the type, it's getting a bit ridiculous at that point.

Answer (score 0):

The book you're using may be out of date. These days c++ has moved in the direction of using free functions for better decoupling.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// an example Gromit
struct Gromit
{
    Gromit(int index) : index(index) {};

    void speak(int i) { std::cout << name() << " speaking " << i << std::endl; }
    void eat(float f) { std::cout << name() << " eating " << f << std::endl; }
    void sleep(char c, double f) { std::cout << name() << " sleeping " << c << " " << f << std::endl; }
    void sit() { std::cout << name() << " sitting" << std::endl; }

private:
    std::string name() const {
        return "Gromit " + std::to_string(index);
    }
    int index;
};

// apply some function object to each item in a container    
template<class Container, class F>
void apply(Container& container, F f)
{
    for (const auto& p : container)
    {
        f(p);
    }

}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Gromit>> dogs;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        dogs.emplace_back(new Gromit(i));

    using namespace std::placeholders;

    // apply dog.speak(1) to each dog in dogs...        
    apply(dogs, std::bind(&Gromit::speak, _1, 1));

    // dog.eat(2.0f) for each dog in dogs...
    apply(dogs, std::bind(&Gromit::eat, _1, 2.0f));

    // ...etc
    apply(dogs, std::bind(&Gromit::sleep, _1, 'z', 3.0));
    apply(dogs, std::bind(&Gromit::sit, _1));
}
```

expected output:

```
Gromit 0 speaking 1
Gromit 1 speaking 1
Gromit 2 speaking 1
Gromit 3 speaking 1
Gromit 4 speaking 1
Gromit 0 eating 2
Gromit 1 eating 2
Gromit 2 eating 2
Gromit 3 eating 2
Gromit 4 eating 2
Gromit 0 sleeping z 3
Gromit 1 sleeping z 3
Gromit 2 sleeping z 3
Gromit 3 sleeping z 3
Gromit 4 sleeping z 3
Gromit 0 sitting
Gromit 1 sitting
Gromit 2 sitting
Gromit 3 sitting
Gromit 4 sitting
```